# Filter something inside group (subset) in R

Tags: r, filter

I have this data.

```
group   name
  1     A
  1     A
  1     A
  1     B
  1     C
  2     A
  2     B
  3     A
  3     B
  3     C
  3     D
```

I would like to filter the group with a standard.
For example, I would like to filter the group inside {A, B, C}.

Group 1 would be filtered because {A, B, C} (unique combination of Group 1) is in {A, B, C}.

Group 2 would be filtered because {A, B} is in {A, B, C}

However, Group 3 would not be filtered because {A, B, C, D} is not the subset of {A, B, C}.

How should I approach this issue?
Additionally, I have more standards (i.e., {A, B, C} and {A, C} ...).

```
structure(list(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
               name = c("A",  "A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "D")), 
               row.names= c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Do you need `df1 %>% group_by(group) %>% filter(all(unique(name) %in% c("A", "B", "C")))` or its opposite `df1 %>% group_by(group) %>% filter(!all(unique(name) %in% c("A", "B", "C")))`

Comment: What is your expected output when you have more standards ?

Comment: In the below answer, 'filter(!(all(stdvec2 %in% name) | all(stdvec1 %in% name)))' is the right approach!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify the standard vector and do a `group_by` `filter`

```
stdvec <- c("A", "B", "C")
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(group) %>%
     filter(all(unique(name) %in% stdvec))
```

and its reverse

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(group) %>% 
   filter(!all(unique(name) %in% stdvec))
```

---

If there are more vectors, it could be

```
stdvec1 <- c("A", "B", "C") 
stdvec2 <- c("A", "C") 
df1 %>%
    group_by(group) %>% 
    filter(all(stdvec2 %in% name) & all(stdvec1 %in% name))
```

and its reverse

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(group) %>% 
   filter(!(all(stdvec2 %in% name) & all(stdvec1 %in% name)))
```

---

Or it could be a `union` of the the multiple vectors compared with the `unique` values of 'name' and check if `all` are included (and negate `!`)

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   filter(!all(unique(name) %in% union(stdvec1, stdvec2)))
```

and

```
 df1 %>% 
   group_by(group) %>% 
   filter(all(unique(name) %in% union(stdvec1, stdvec2)))
```

If there are many `vectors`, use `reduce` to `union`

```
library(purrr)
nm1 <- mget(ls(pattern = "^stdvec\\d+$")) %>%
               reduce(union) 
df1 %>%
         group_by(group) %>%
         filter(all(unique(name) %in%  nm1))
```

Comment: Thanks. If I have more stdvec (standards), How should I apply that? for exmapme, stdvec1 <- c("A", "B", "C") stdvec2 <- c("A", "C")

Comment: Thanks. What I do is 'filter(!(all(stdvec2 %in% name) | all(stdvec1 %in% name)))
' format, but there are 30 standards so I should expand the '|' 30 times. Is there any solution?

Comment: @Juhyeon No, that can be done easily `lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = "^stdvec\\d+$")); df1 %>% group_by(group) %>% filter(map(lst1, ~ all(.x %in% name)) %>% reduce(`|`) %>% `!`)`